# Por que o símbolo “@” está sendo traduzido para “¿” quando enviado via SMS a partir de um dispositivo Android 2.3?

Tags: android, codificação-de-caracteres, sms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para o Android que envia comandos para um equipamento remoto através de SMS. Os comandos utilizados são todos mensagens de texto comuns, e alguns deles são iniciados com o prefixo `A@@`. Para testar o aplicativo enviei alguns "comandos" para um telefone Android 4.3 e para um Android 2.3.

Quando rodo o aplicativo no Android 4.3, o SMS é recebido normalmente em qualquer dispositivo, mas se eu uso o aplicativo para mandar comandos a partir de um Android 2.3 os comandos são recebidos como `A¿¿` pelo telefone Android 4.3 mas chegam normalmente como  `A@@` tanto em um Android 2.3 quanto num iPhone. No equipamento "alvo", que utiliza um modem GSM, a mensagem chega como `A` (caractere "A" mais 2 espaços - símbolo ASCII 0x20), então suspeito que o envio está sendo feito usando um *encoding* diferente. O estranho é que o símbolo `@` nem é um caractere ASCII estendido, então fico imaginando porque teria sido codificado em outro *charset* que não o ASCII.

Alguém pode explicar o que esta acontecendo? Se o dispositivo Android 2.3 está realmente usando outro *encoding*, há alguma maneira de forçá-lo para ASCII antes de enviar o SMS?

A função que envia os comandos é a seguinte:

```java
@Override
public void sendCommand(String command) {
    SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
    PendingIntent piSent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                                       new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
    PendingIntent piDelivered=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                                            new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
    String phone = txtPhone.getText().toString();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, command, piSent, piDelivered);
}
```

Onde o parâmetro `command` é sempre a concatenação do prefixo com algum outro texto, assim:

```java
String SmsPrefix = new String("A@@");
sendCommand(SmsPrefix + "AT+DEACT");
```

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que você pode resolver isso apenas utilizando `sendMultipartTextMessage()` ao invés de `sendTextMessage()` testa aí e me diz se funcionou

Comment: @PauloRoberto, obrigado pela dica... realmente li em alguma resposta no SO que isso seria possível, mas acabei de testar e ficou na mesma :/ No Android 4.3 continua chegando `A¿¿`

Comment: Você testou todos os aparelhos com a mesma operadora/SIMCard? Encontrei problemas muito semelhantes de substituição de símbolos em SMS e no final meu problema estava na operadora.

Comment: Bem observado @molusco, o Android 2.3 estava com chip da TIM e o iPhone também.. o Android 4.3 era da Vivo. Vou experimentar trocar os chips amanhã pra ver o que dá.

Comment: @molusco, você acertou na mosca. Qualquer SMS enviado da TIM pelo menos para a Claro chega com o `¿` no lugar do `@`. A versão do Android realmente não importa nem um pouco. Prepara a resposta aí que essa é tua! hehe..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Resposta:

O problema real é que o simbolo está sendo "substituído" pela **Operadora** e não pelo **Android**, você pode notar ao realizar testes com todos os aparelhos utilizando a mesma operadora/SIMCard.

Anteriormente, encontrei problemas muito semelhantes ao seu, de substituição de símbolos em SMS, e acabei descobrindo que meu problema estava na operadora.

Essa "substituição" é algo que varia de operadora para operadora e ainda varia de estado para estado (*algo legado das operadoras locais/menores?*)

## Solução:

A solução que encontrei foi achar símbolos que não fossem substituídos por nenhuma das operadoras testadas. Infelizmente não me recordo, por isso não sei te dizer quais são os símbolos que não eram substituídos, mas lembro que o "pipe" (**`|`**) teve bons resultados.

Comment: É.. no meu caso agora estou utilizando `*` no lugar do `@` e está indo bem. Valeu!